# Problem with Converting XY Coordinates to LatLon

Tags: gdal, c#, coordinates, coordinate-system

Here is the function that I use to convert from pixel x,y to lat,lon coordinate:

```
    public static Coordinate imageToWorld(Dataset gds, int x, int y)
    {
        double[] adfGeoTransform = new double[6];
        double[] p = new double[3];
        gds.GetGeoTransform(adfGeoTransform);
        p[0] = adfGeoTransform[0] + adfGeoTransform[1] * x + adfGeoTransform[2] * y;
        p[1] = adfGeoTransform[3] + adfGeoTransform[4] * x + adfGeoTransform[5] * y;

        OSGeo.OSR.SpatialReference src = new OSGeo.OSR.SpatialReference("");
        string s = gds.GetProjectionRef();
        src.ImportFromWkt(ref s);
        //src.SetUTM(41, 1);
        OSGeo.OSR.SpatialReference wgs84 = new OSGeo.OSR.SpatialReference("");
        wgs84.SetWellKnownGeogCS("WGS84");
        OSGeo.OSR.CoordinateTransformation ct = new OSGeo.OSR.CoordinateTransformation(src, wgs84);
        ct.TransformPoint(p);
        return new Coordinate(p[0], p[1]);
    }
```

but this function doesn't work for utm projection and gives incorrect longitude. 
for example for an image with the following WKT it gives 35.25,3.65 but it should be 35.29,61.17 @(x=0,y=0). if I uncomment line 12 it gives correct result only for this image.

> PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 41N",GEOGCS["WGS
>   84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS
>   84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","32641"]]

Comment: I would check the source code of http://www.gdal.org/gdaltransform.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say, but I'm assuming the PROJCS string in your question is the string being read from your dataset. There are several errors in the string. Here's what I found on SpatialReference.org:

```
PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 41N",
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.01745329251994328,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
UNIT["metre",1,
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
PARAMETER["central_meridian",63],
PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","32641"],
AXIS["Easting",EAST],
AXIS["Northing",NORTH]]
```

Your central meridian is wrong, as is the false easting.

Comment: thanks for your response. when I open this image with "global mapper", it shows correct lat/long. how that sofware can generate desired results if the string have errors?

Comment: about all I can guess is that GlobalMapper is reading just the EPSG value, or even the UTM 41 zone 41N, and ignoring the actual projection parameters in the string